# A mixture of things that offer/offers

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, grammatical-number, numbers, singular

> A mixture of things that offer

Or,

> A mixture of things that offers

It is not obvious to me which one is correct because mixture is singular but things is plural.

Comment: Does the mixture offer something, or do the individual things in the mixture each offer something?

Comment: Yes. The mixture of things offer something (e.g. a mixture of programs that offer/offers).

Comment: If you are saying that the mixture has benefits _because_ it includes several programs, it's _(a mixture of things) that offers_. If the emphasis was on each program bringing its own benefit, it would be _a mixture of (things that offer)_. Do you see the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the subject is singular, use "*offers*", for example:

> He offers a cleaning service.

If the subject is plural, use "*offer*", for example:

> They offer a cleaning service.

---

In your example of "a mixture of things", although there are plural "things" they are being *collectively* described as "a mixture of things". This should be treated as a *collective noun*. As collective nouns are singular you should therefore use "*offers*".